# Strange Clock output on AVR

Tags: avr

I have programmed my ATtiny1616 to output the clock on a pin. 
Here is my reading:

[image: Scope Reading]

Why is there all that ripple?
How might I reduce it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheap oscilloscope showing 16 MHz square wave](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455356/cheap-oscilloscope-showing-16-mhz-square-wave). Look at the answers in that question, which explain why you see waveform shapes like yours, when all the harmonics of a high-frequency square wave cannot be displayed on a lower-bandwidth oscilloscope. (Probing technique may also be causing the displayed overshoot.)

Comment: The linked question definitely is informative, that said this is not a low bandwidth scope.  You may be seeing transmission line effects and probe compensation, band limiting issues would be more symmetric.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How do you know this is not a "low bandwidth scope"? It looks like a Rigol DS1000Z series scope to me, which has a bandwidth of 50-100Mhz depending on model. Pretty similar to the one in the linked question.

Comment: @SamGibson the linked question answered mine. Thx.